# iTunes Connect: dSYM removed when sending build to review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, dsym

Since a few weeks, I have a problem with the symbolicated logs from my application:
I upload a binary and include the symbols. When using the build in TestFlight (internal and external) everything works fine and I get the crash-logs I'm expecting. But as soon as I send the build (I checked before. iTunes Connect tells me, that the dSYM are available) to app review, the dSYM disappear.

At first I thought, release builds never include the symbols, but my first release-versions have symbols included.
So why has none of my latest releases dSYMs? The first build with this problem was uploaded on 31th October this year.